# Regular expression that allows only a specific special character when it has a specific length

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I need a regular expression that matches these cases:

```
EXAMPLE1
1EXAMPLE
EXAMPLE
*****
```

Not Match

```
EXAMPLE 1
EXAMPLE.
**EXAMPLE**
EXAMPLE**
**EXAMPLE
*****EXAMPLE
EXA MPLE
*******
EXAMPLEÑ
```

I try with this regex `^(\*{0,5}?)([a-zA-Z0-9])*$` [(DEMO)](https://regex101.com/r/NTSpjN/1)
but the regular expression matches cases like these which I don't need to match:

```
*****EXAMPLE
**EXAMPLE
****
```

They should only match when the asterisks have a length of 5 or words without special characters or asterisks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match only cases where the entire string either only contains letters and digits, or else is exactly 5 asterisks, you can use the regex `^(\*{5}|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$` .

This assumes empty strings are not allowed. If you want to allow empty strings, replace `+` with `*`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not totally clear to me what to match in your case, however, something like

```
(^\*{5}$)|(^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$)
```

Should do the trick.